# how to copy a sitecollection with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Does any one know how to copy a site collection using PowerShell.
I used this :

```
Copy-SPSite http://contoso/sites/OldTeam -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content -TargetUrl http://contoso/sites/NewTeam
```

but it show an error:
copy-SPSite is it not a command.

Comment: Are you sure you used the SharePoint Management Shell?

Comment: Make sure to add the Sharepoint cmdldts in Powershell. add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

Comment: yes i used SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Type in powershell and tell the result -> Get-SPFarm . also https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/articles/pages/there-is-more-than-one-way-to-access-sharepoint-2010-powershell-cmdlets.aspx

Comment: what error you are getting? could you please past from powershell window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use sharepoint backup restore feature to clone sharepoint site.

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://myspsite" -Path "C:\backups\myspsite.bak" -Force -Confirm:$False

Restore-SPSite "http://myspsite:81" -Path C:\backups\myspsite-81.bak -Force -Confirm:$False
```

For more details:

http://www.topsharepoint.com/clone-a-sharepoint-2010-site-using-powershell

http://www.bradleyschacht.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharePoint Management Shell for this, it includes the SharePoint-Commands.

Comment: yes i used SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: When typing Copy-SP you can use [Tab] for autocomplete and if there's nothing wrong with you Shell you should also find Copy-SPSite.