# Copy-SPSite not recognised?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to copy a site with power shell using SP2010 Enterprise and the SharePoint management shell but the cmdlet does not recognize the Copy-SPSite term!?

It is not permissions as I am admin and I have tried the add spshell admin command too.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to console as "run as administrator"?can you share the screen shot of the error?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113984/how-to-copy-a-sitecollection-with-powershell

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113984/how-to-copy-a-sitecollection-with-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-SPSite wasn't supported in 2010, it only applies to 2013. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161280(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Omar, thanks. Do you know a way I can copy an existing site collection in 2010??

Answer (score 0):

To copy a site collection in SP 2010 follow the instruction below.

If want to copy within same Web Application

- take the backup of existing site collection
- Create a new Content Database(otherwise will get error)
- restore the site collection with different name.

If going to different Web app then no need of new content Database. Simply do the backup and restore.

Comment: Thanks. If I create a new content DB within the same web app can I perform multiple restores to it of different site collections? Also with a backup and restore does the newly named site have any connection with the original??

Comment: Yes, you can restore multiple sites in that content DB just make sure add the database parameter in your Command. Normally their will be no connection with old site...unless you have hardcoded url....with duplicate sites risk is user will get two results for same file, again duoble alerts...as you have two sites with same content.